# Take words from string and convert to array

Tags: javascript, regex

Seems simple enough but I can't find an answer on Stack that has a good solution. Feel free to point me in the right direction.

The regex should allow me to do a javascript `split` to convert a string into an array. The basic test is that:

```
test1 test2, tes-t3; t"e's-----4.      test5
```

should be split into an array that contains:

```
[test1, test2, tes-t3, t"e's-----4, test5]
```

Best way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't see any regex...What have you tried so far? Check here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.split(/[\s,;.]+/)`:

```
var s = 'test1 test2, tes-t3; t"e\'s-----4.      test5';
s.split(/[\s,;.]+/)
=> ["test1", "test2", "tes-t3", "t"e's-----4", "test5"]
```

or `String.match(/[-'"\w]+/g)`:

```
s.match(/[-'"\w]+/g)
=> ["test1", "test2", "tes-t3", "t"e's-----4", "test5"]
```

Comment: maybe you should use regex `[\s,;\.]+` to split instead of `[\s,;.]+`?

Comment: @Angga, You don't need to escape dot(`.`) inside `[]`.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so that it doesn't count ending spaces? Currently if the input has `var s = 'test1 '` (space at the end) it splits to `['test1', '']`.

Comment: @Jascination, Which one do you want as a result: `['test1 ']` (with trailing space remained), `['test1']` (no trailing space)?

Comment: The latter, `['test1']`. Apologies, it's hard to be super-specific with questions when you're new to this sort of thing!

Comment: @Jascination, The second code in my answer will give you the expected result.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try this also, "test1 test2, tes-t3; t\"e's-----4.      test5".split(/\s+|[,.;]\s*/);